# Can we ask questions related to R Programming?

Tags: discussion, on-topic

Questions related to programming/coding is mostly related to [Stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/).

R is a programming language for statistical computing. Can we ask questions related to R-programming??

Comment: One of the reasons for closing a question is "This question appears to be off-topic because EITHER it is not about statistics, machine learning, data analysis, data mining, or data visualization, OR it focuses on programming, debugging, or performing routine operations within a statistical computing platform. If the latter, you could try the support links we maintain." Some useful discussion here: https://stats.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5286/why-do-we-have-a-tensorflow-tag-if-questions-about-programming-are-off-topic

Comment: The policy is in one word No, which does nothing to stop decisions being difficult in grey areas. We could speculate about an alternative history if Stack Overflow hadn't started first. Some standard points to ponder: If R questions are allowed, what extra volume of questions would be implied? If questions in any statistical or other programming language or software environment you care about are allowed, so also are  questions in all other software you don't care about. Naturally every user's private fantasy criterion is "questions of interest to me are allowed, and no others".

Comment: There's a criterion that qualifies a question that relates to code (though perhaps subject to some substantial differences in interpretation) -- that it *requires statistical expertise to understand or answer*.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Programming questions are off-topic, but there are some grey areas. It's fine to ask here if the core of the question is statistical. From the help page https://stats.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic:

> There are certain subjects that will probably get better responses on
> our sister sites. If your question is about
>
> - Programming, ask on Stack Overflow. If the language is statistically
>   oriented (such as R, SAS, Stata, SPSS, etc.), then decide based on the
>   nature of your question: if it needs statistical expertise to
>   understand or answer, ask it here; if it's about the implementation of
>   an algorithm, routine data processing, or details of the language,
>   then please refer to the collection of links to resources we maintain.